# Insert to MongoDB collection that has unique key with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection called englishWords, and the unique index is the "word" field.
When I do this

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

tasovshik = MongoClient()
db = tasovshik.tongler
coll = db.englishWords

f = open('book.txt')
for word in f.read().split():
    coll.insert( { "word": word } } )
```

I get this error message

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: tongler.englishWords.$word_1 dup key: { : "Harry" }
```

, but it stops to insert when the first existing word is to be inserted.

I do not want to implement the check of existence, I want to use the benefits of unique index with no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
for word in f.read().split():
    try:
        coll.insert( { "word": word } } )
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        continue
```

This will ignore errors.

And also, did you drop the collection before trying?

Comment: No I didn't, I am going to take many text files and insert all English words to that collection, so I will not drop it.

and it python drops this error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
NameError: name 'pymongo' is not defined

Comment: I added import pymongo at the beginning and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid unnecessary exception handling, you could do an upsert:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

tasovshik = MongoClient()
db = tasovshik.tongler
coll = db.englishWords

for word in f.read().split():
    coll.replace_one({'word': word}, {'word': word}, True)
```

The last argument specifies that MongoDB should insert the value if it does not already exist.

Here's [the documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one).

---

**EDIT**: For even faster performances for a long list of words, you could do it in bulk like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

tasovshik = MongoClient()
db = tasovshik.tongler
coll = db.englishWords

bulkop = coll.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for word in f.read().split():
    bulkop.find({'word':word}).upsert()

bulkop.execute()
```

Taken from [bulk operations documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html)

Comment: sorry but is upsert efficient in this case?

Comment: It is since you have a unique index on the `word` column. If you want efficiency over the long list of words, I'll update my answer to provide a even quicker variant.

Comment: .. on the `word` *property, not column :)

Comment: the second variant returns this 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    bulkop.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-3.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pymongo/bulk.py", line 628, in execute
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-3.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pymongo/bulk.py", line 450, in execute
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: No operations to execute

Comment: Does it return that every time or just after the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code and everything looks good except that you have an extra `}` at the last line. Delete that, and you don't have the drop any collection. Every `insert`, creates it's own batch of data, so there is no need for dropping the previous collection.

Well, error msg indicates that the key `Harry` is already inserted and you are trying to insert again with the same key. Looks like this in not your entire code?